# Can XOR be expressed using SKI combinators?

Tags: boolean, logic, lambda-calculus, combinators, combinatory-logic

I have question about SKI-Combinators.

Can XOR (exclusive or) be expressed using `S`  and `K` combinators only?

I have

```
True = Cancel
False = (Swap Cancel)
```

where

```
Cancel x y = K x y = x   
Swap: ff x y = S ff x y = ff y x
```

Comment: `I` can be represented as `S K K`. So, if you can express `NOR` using `SKI`, you can do it with just `SK`.

Comment: Would it infix? and how about bracketing? (p.s I have tried quite a few ways not successful yet) Thanks!

Comment: Assuming you enclose your logical connectives in parentheses, i.e. `NOR = (... some expression ...)`: **(1)** `NOR` cannot be expressed as a postfix operator (as `AND`) -- to see this observe that
`T T NOR = T`, no matter what `NOR` is (but should be `F`);

**(2)** `NOR` cannot be expressed as an infix operator --
`F NOR F = F` (but should be `T`)

Comment: Ah yes of course! actually I have made a huge mistake of asking the wrong question! I meant to ask XOR not NOR! Very sorry!

Answer (score 4):

**Booleans**

Your question is a bit unclear on the details, but it seems that what you mean is that you have the following representation of booleans:

```
T := K
F := S K
```

This works because it means the following reductions hold:

```
T t e => t
F t e => e
```

in other words, `b t e` can be interpreted as `IF b THEN t ELSE e`.

**XOR in terms of `IF _ THEN _ ELSE _`**

So given this framework, how do we implement XOR? We can formulate XOR as an `IF` expression:

```
xor x y := IF x THEN (not y) ELSE y = (IF x THEN not ELSE id) y
```

which can be eta-reduced to

```
XOR x := IF x THEN not ELSE id = x not id
```

**Some function combinators**

We have `id = SKK` as standard, and `not` can be expressed as `flip`, since `flip b t e = b e t = IF b THEN e ELSE t = IF (not b) THEN t ELSE e`. [`flip` it self is quite involved](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32117337/477476) but doable as

```
flip := S (S (K (S (KS) K)) S) (KK)
```

Now we just need to figure out a way to write a function that takes `x` and applies it on the two terms `NOT` and `ID`. To get there, we first note that if we set

```
app := id
```

then

```
app f x = (id f) x = f x
```

and so,

```
(flip app) x f = f x
```

We are almost there, since everything so far shows that

```
((flip app) id) ((flip app) not x) = ((flip app) not x) id = (x not) id = x not id
```

The last step is to make that last line point-free on `x`. We can do that with a function composition operator:

```
((flip app) id) ((flip app) not x) = compose ((flip app) id) ((flip app) not) x
```

where the requirement on `compose` is that

```
compose f g x = f (g x)
```

which we can get by setting

```
compose f g := S (K f) g
```

**Putting it all together**

To summarize, we got

```
xor := compose ((flip app) id) ((flip app) not)
```

or, fully expanded:

```
xor = S (K ((flip app) id)) ((flip app) not)
    = S (K ((flip app) (SKK))) ((flip app) flip)
    = S (K ((flip SKK) (SKK))) ((flip SKK) flip)
    = S (K (((S (S (K (S (KS) K)) S) (KK)) SKK) (SKK))) (((S (S (K (S (KS) K)) S) (KK)) SKK) (S (S (K (S (KS) K)) S) (KK)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes! In 2020, Stephen Wolfram [constructed combinators](https://writings.stephenwolfram.com/2020/12/combinators-a-centennial-view/) for all 16 two-input Boolean functions, including XOR. It turns out XOR can be expressed as s[s[s[s[s]][s[s[s[k]]]][s]]][k] where k represents the value True and s[k] represents the value False.

For example, here is the combinator form of XOR operating on true and false the Wolfram Language.

```
true = k;
false = s[k];
ResourceFunction["CombinatorFixedPoint"][s[s[s[s[s]][s[s[s[k]]]][s]]][k][true][false], SKGlyphs -> {s, k}]
```

It returns the expected output – True:

`k`