# lambda calculus xor expression by true false

Tags: functional-programming, xor, church-encoding

I am trying to understand xor in context on lambda calculus. I understand xor (Exclusive or) as boolean logic operation in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or
and the truth table of xor.

But how why is it true as a xor b=(a)((b)(false)(true))(b)
from http://safalra.com/lambda-calculus/boolean-logic/ 
it is indeed what what expect in lambda calculus. When I saw 
true=λab.a
false=λab.b
I kinda have to see the true and false as a lambda calc true and false since it returns the first element in case of true. But is it correct to understand that the xor here is also a name but not the same as xor in boolean logic?

Comment: by the way, I assume true=λab.a
false=λab.b         is the same thing as true=(λa.b.)a
false=(λa.b.) b      the latter is more text book style

Comment: lambda calculus logic is the same as in boolean logic. in lamba calculus there are no values, only symbols (names). TRUE is not only function, but also a name that describes it. and when the result of evaluation is λab.a, it's not important it's a function, more important is it's a function described by symbol TRUE.

Comment: also see: [*Church Encoding*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Church_encoding) – all values are functions, even numbers `zero := λf.λx.x`, `one := λf.λx.f x`, `two := λf.λx.f (f x)`, etc

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Intuitively, we can think of A XOR B as

1. if A, then **not** B
2. otherwise, B

.... or in some pseudocode:

```
func xor (a,b)
  if a then
    return not b
  else
    return b
```

---

Let's get lambda calculusing

```
true := λa.λb.a
false := λa.λb.b

true a b
// a

false a b
// b
```

next we'll do `not`

```
not := λp.p false true

not true a b
// b

not false a b
// a
```

we can do `if` next (note, that this is sort of silly since `true` and `false` already behave like `if`)

```
if := λp.λa.λb.p a b

if true a b
// a

if false a b
// b
```

Ok, lastly write `xor`

```
xor := λa.λb.if a (not b) b

(xor true true) a b
// b

(xor true false) a b
// a

(xor false true) a b
// a

(xor false false) a b
// b
```

Remember `if` is kind of dumb here, we can just remove it

```
xor := λa.λb.a (not b) b
```

Now if we want to write it all with pure lambda, just replace the `not` with its definition

```
xor := λa.λb.a (not b) b
->β [ not := λp.p false true ]

xor := λa.λb.a ((λp.p false true) b) b
->β [ p := b ]

xor := λa.λb.a (b false true) b
```

At *this* point, you can see we have the definition from your question

> a xor b = (a)((b)(false)(true))(b)

But of course that introduced additional free variables `false` and `true` – you can replace those with a couple additional beta reductions

```
xor := λa.λb.a (b false true) b
->β [ false := (λa.λb.b) ]

xor := λa.λb.a (b (λa.λb.b) true) b
->β [ true := (λa.λb.a) ]

// pure lambda definition
xor := λa.λb.a (b (λa.λb.b) (λa.λb.a)) b
```

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37119381/can-xor-be-expressed-using-ski-combinators – cool answer showing XOR derived from [SKI combinators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SKI_combinator_calculus)

Answer (score 0):

Consider a(b F T)b,the middle expression is essentially (not b),so a(not b)b gives true only when a and b are different.